# Grouping data in a sorted list

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

In splunk, I want to group data in order after it is sorted.

**sample events**

```
Time: 1:00 server: A .....
Time: 1:01 server: A ......
Time: 1:02 server: B ......
Time: 1:03 server: A ......
Time: 1:04 server: A ......
Time: 1:05 server: C ......
Time: 1:06 server: A ......
```

***I want to see***

```
Server: A Events: 2
Server: B Events: 1
Server: A Events: 2
Server: C Events: 1
Server: A Events: 1
```

Extra points if I can get start and end times for each set too.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp server=* 
| stats min(_time) as First max(_time) as Last count as Events by server
| rename server as Server
| eval First=strftime(First,"%c"), Last=strftime(Last,"%c")
| table First Last Events Server
```

Should give you a table like the following:

```
First    | Last     | Events | Server
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<time>   | <time>   | 7      | serverA
```

Etc

Comment: Would this give me only the first and last per server? And not in order of the path a request took between servers? I need the find the path, Server A then B , then A, then C. But roll up every that was done on each visit

Comment: @Ishey4 - I misunderstood :) This'll need a `streamstats` instead. Give me a few to try it out before sharing